# if statement returns space in front of string

Tags: babel, languages

I have defined a macro (using `\def`) `\documentlanguage` which should be set to either `german` or `english`.
Now I want a second macro (or command) which returns `english` when `\documentlanguage` is `english` and `ngerman` (because of package `babel`) when `\documentlanguage` is `german`.

This is my solution:

```
\newcommand{\babellanguage}{
\if\documentlanguage{german}%
ngerman%
\else%
english%
\fi%
}
```

I then use it like this:

```
\begin{document}
% set language
\expandafter\selectlanguage\expandafter{\babellanguage}
```

But then I get the following error:

```
Package babel Error: You haven't defined the language  english yet.
```

Seems like there is an space in front of `\babellanguage`. How do I fix this?

Thanks!

**Edit:**
the definition of `\documentlanguage`:

```
\def\documentlanguage{german}
```

Comment: You're missing a trailing `%` at the end of the first line

Comment: @egreg I know you are an expert on `%` but you might have mentioned what `\if` does.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I assumed the OP has correctly defined `\documentlanguage` (which might not be the case, of course).

Comment: @egreg @DavidCarlisle I defined documentlanguage as `\def\documentlanguage{german}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

after

```
\newcommand\documentlanguage{german}
\newcommand{\babellanguage}{
\if\documentlanguage{german}%
ngerman%
\else%
english%
\fi%
}
```

then the expansion of `\babellanguage` starts with a space (from the newline after `%`) You need a `%` after `{` (and not after `\else` or `\fi` where white space is ignored anyway)

But then it will expand

```
  \if\documentlanguage{german}
```

`\if` expands until it finds two non expandable tokens which it then compares so this is

```
 \if german{german}
```

and it will compare the character codes of `g` and `e` which are not equal.

As you need the test to be expandable a simple way would be

```
\def\babellanguage{%
  \expandafter\ifx\csname l-\documentlanguage\endcsname\relax
    \documentlanguage
   \else
     \csname l-\documentlanguage\endcsname
\fi}
```

so `\babellanguage` will just expand to `\documentlanguage` by default but you can use

```
 \expandafter\def\csname l-german\endcsname{ngerman}
```

so `\babellanguage` expands if `\documentlanguage` is to `ngerman` and you can add any number of similar language aliases.

So putting it alltogether and fully expanding the macro before teh call to `\selectlanguage` produces

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}
\begin{document}


\def\documentlanguage{german}

\def\babellanguage{%
  \expandafter\ifx\csname l-\documentlanguage\endcsname\relax
  \documentlanguage
   \else
     \csname l-\documentlanguage\endcsname
\fi}



 \expandafter\def\csname l-german\endcsname{ngerman}

%need to expand before `\selectlanguage`
\edef\tmp{\noexpand\selectlanguage{\babellanguage}}\tmp


\end{document}
```

Comment: if I add an % after {, it returns the whole if statement as string:

Comment: `You haven't defined the language ifgerman{german}ngerman\ifgerman{german}ngermanenglish yet.`

Comment: doesn't babel already support aliases for german/ngerman etc without having to do this by hand?

Comment: Yeah there is \babeltags or sth like this, but this didn't work for the \selectlanguage command

Comment: @michidk `\selectlanguage` suppresses expansion so you need to force the macro to expand if you want to do this, see edited answer above.

Comment: Yes this already works. I just use `\expandafter\selectlanguage\expandafter{\babellanguage}`

Comment: Okay thanks, got it working with your code! I just dont understand why `\expandafter\selectlanguage\expandafter{\babellanguage}` doesnt work with your code.

Comment: @michidk basically it fails as `\selectlanguage` is a wrapper for `\def\bbl@set@language#1{%
  \edef\languagename{%
    \ifnum\escapechar=\expandafter`\string#1\@empty`  where `\string` is applied after one level of expansion so you can put a macro expanding to the language but not a macro expanding to tests that eventually expand to the language. the `\edef` in my answer resolves the tests before calling `\selectlanguage`

Comment: the version with the `\if ` test in the question doesn't work ever even if it doesn't give an error it doesn't select the intended language.